# Is there a way to beat Blindsight?

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light, stealth

Blindsight allows creatures to see invisible creatures (p. 183 PHB):

> A creature with blindsight can perceive its surroundings without relying on sight, within a specific radius.

We are currently adventuring in an area where there are several Red Dragons, who we do believe have blindsight, and we want to remain undetected. So *invisibility*, even if paired with *pass without trace* may not do the trick. We also happen to have access to all Wizard spells in the game up to level 7 inclusive (we stole the spell book collection of a lich).

Is there any other spell that we could use, other than *Etherealness* (which will not allow us to interact with the environment, and which we are not high enough level to cast on several characters), to remain undetected? Maybe some mind affecting enchantment, that makes us a "Other people's problem" like in *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*?

Comment: I assume "stay far enough away" isn't what you are looking for? You are wanting to effectively walk right past a dragon guard?

Comment: Yes, "Stay far away" is what we are currently doing, but it may not work in the dungeon environment we are now in.

Comment: I think we've got a dupe.

Comment: And related: [Do true dragons use echolocation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/202213)

Comment: That last link shows hide from dragons as a spell, 3.5 really did think of everything. I think I missed out .